# Using many-to-many items before save()

Tags: python, django

I am using models which has many-to-many fields

What I want to do is like this.

1. Fetch items from web and store in memory
2. Filter items. remove or add many-to-many field.
3. Save in database.

my model

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(genre)
```

filter

```
tweets = fetchfromweb()

filtered = []
for tweet in tweets:
    if tweet.text == x :
        tweet.genre.add(genreObj)
        filtered.append(tweet)
    else:
        pass

for i in filtered: // write in db
    i.save()
```

However it shows error where `tweet.genre.add(genreObj)`.

Without save(), I couldn't access many-to-many fields.

so for now my solution is like this.

```
tweets = fetchfromweb()

filtered = []
for tweet in tweets:
    tweet.save() ## save and create manytomanyfield
    if tweet.text == x :
        tweet.genre.add(genreObj)
        tweet.save()
    else:
        tweet.remove()
```

However it require many db insert and remove, is it good practice???

Or is there any good ideas ???

Answer (score 2):

You can't add M2M records before `tweet` is saved because `tweet` needs to have a primary key to be set before adding M2M related records. You can check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships).

Not sure if this gona work but you can try [atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) transaction:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    for tweet in tweets:
        tweet.save() ## save and create manytomanyfield
        if tweet.text == x :
           tweet.genre.add(genreObj)
    else:
        tweet.remove()
```

Also, you do not need to call `save` again after adding M2M records.

Comment: I undesrstood . I must use save() before . thank you very much